# PhpStorm and Symfony plugin: completion in config YAML's in Flex layout

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, symfony-flex

This week I updated a project to Symfony 4 and Flex.

It used to be that the PhpStorm Symfony plugin provided code completion in the `app/config.yml` file for all keys and sometimes values.

However, now that that file is split up in multiple files in `config/packages`, I am not getting any code completion anymore.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this not supported anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it wasn't possible yet with the plugin, but I openend an issue on GitHub and the awesome developer fixed it very fast. See https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/1344

Note that currently there is still a small bug but seeing how fast he fixed the initial issue it will probably be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure in Symfony 4 is different than previous versions of the framework.

You will have have to change the folders in your Symfony-plugin.

You can find the settings under `Languages & Frameworks` > `PHP` > `Symfony`.

Comment: I did check this out already indeed, but couldn't figure out to what settings to set it. It seems your example is also not correct, since the `app` directory doesn't exist anymore

Comment: It was just to show the settings page of the plugin, but i'll remove it.

Comment: But do you know what it should be? I couldn't get it to work.. I had:
* Translation root path: var/cache/dev/translations
* App directory: (empty)
* Web directory: public

But that didn't seem to help.